# CCleaner cannot clean the cache and cookies for Metro UI Browsers

Tags: windows-8, browser, cookies, browser-cache, ccleaner

I have CCleaner Professional v 3.24.1850 installed on my Windows 8 laptop. Whenever I run the cleaner, it clears the cache, cookies, history, etc., but only for Desktop browsers. Nothing happens to the Metro UI version of the browser.

Is there a way to fix this, or is there an alternative application that works under Windows 8?

Comment: Errm, did you ask the CCleaner support? They are generally very helpful

Answer (score 0):

[CCleaner does not officially support](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/faq/installing/what-operating-systems-does-ccleaner-support) Windows 8 as of this posting date (11-7-2012)

EDIT:

But if you [go to this page](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) and look in the release notes it says

> Optimized architecture for 64-bit builds of Windows 7 and 8.

So maybe it is still not fully developed for cleaning the metro apps yet.

You might ask in the [Piriform community forum](http://forum.piriform.com/) or ["contact us"](http://www.piriform.com/about) page
.

[image]

Comment: Any other software or app for that task ??

Comment: Strange, this page [says it does support W8](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) in the release notes, maybe they are still tweaking it.

Comment: @developer Whats wrong with the standard clear history+cache method?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so lets say you were browsing birthdaygift.xxx and nobody must known. Time to clear your [history](http://www.howtogeek.com/124015/how-to-clear-your-browser-cache-in-the-metro-version-of-internet-explorer/).

1. Click the gears icon in IE10 and go to settings
2. Internet Options
3. Delete browsing history

[image]
[image]